# Sudden traffic fall related with DNS Error

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, googlebot

We juts notice a real time traffic fall in our website , from 1500 visits to 600 real time.

This is extremely rare, I do a check on the behavor from the past weeks and we notice , that GoogleBot couldn't access the site because of a DNS error.

Odd thing because I do several test on DNS side and everything is showing correctly.

So in the las 4 weeks we do this:

We migrate our site to an other infrastructure (wpengine)
Add a SSL Certificate from Lets-encrypt
Add a Test GA Property in GTM , so we can migrate to GTM (So there are 2 properties running in our site)
Add a ScorllDept Event (http://scrolldepth.parsnip.io/)

And that was all.

I really know that DNS Error is affecting me also , but I can't verify or fix , because every DNS test I made turn out perfect.

What do you suggest?

Comment: Are you saying you changed from HTTP to HTTPS? If so, have you redirected HTTP to HTTPS? Are you looking at HTTPS in GA and Search Console? If you have not redirected HTTP to HTTPS then you have to consider both. Cheers!!

Comment: You say it is a DNS error, but you don't post anything about your DNS settings.   What are your name servers?    Who hosts them?   What are your A and CNAME records?